# MySQL: select all the data but if contains ' * ', then show the last four characters

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, subquery, oracle-sqldeveloper

Something like:

SELECT IF( [call_history.callerid contains '*'], [if it contains, keep last four char], [if not, return ' '(not null)] ) AS 'test'

FROM call_history

ORDER BY start DESC;

Comment: David use a `case/when`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend reading the manual page on string functions built into MySQL's flavor of SQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

For example:

```
SELECT IF(LOCATE(callerid, '*'), SUBSTRING(callerid, -4), '') AS 'test'
FROM call_history
ORDER BY start DESC;
```